# Bilirubin metabolism and UGT1A1 inhibition in human vs. monkey?

Tags: physiology, metabolism

In human UGT1A1 seems to be the only relevant enzyme to glucuronidate unconjugated bilirubin into excreted forms. Is the pathway the same for e.g. the Cynomolgus monkey (Macaca fascicularis) in vivo? In case UGT1A1 is potently inhibited are there any other potential enzyme to metabolise/glucuronidate unconjugated bilirubin in monkey? Furthermore, bilirubin is analytically challenging in UGT1A1 inhibition studies in vitro. Estradiol (3-glucuronidation) has been used as a specific substrate for human UGT1A1. Do you know any substrates known to be specific for monkey UGT1A1?  Any reference would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

UGT1A1 is common among most mammals that produce bilirubin (rats too). I haven't seen any evidence to suggest an alternate pathway in mammals of bilirubin metabolism. Look into gilbert's syndrome patients (they have a SNP which is a mutuation that causes UGT1A1 to be less efficient and thus a rise in plasma unconjugated bilirubin).

Also, bilirubin analysis from plasma/tissues is fairly straight forward with HPLC or LCMS assays. UGT1A1 inhibition in vitro however, is still a challenge. I think the trick will be to use CRISPR to knock it out.

Comment: It would be great if you could add some references.